# How to get two collections output in a single document in MongoDb in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Lets say I am having two collections named CollectionA and CollectionB, Both collection have **different fields**.
CollectionA will have multiple documents with Same field,
CollectionB contain only one document

Example

```
CollectionA
    {
       "UniqeId" :1,
       "Hobbies" : "Eating"
    },
    {
       "UniqeId" :2,
       "Hobbies" : "Sleeping"
    },
    {
       "UniqeId" :3,
       "Hobbies" : "Walking"
    }


CollectionB
    {
       "UserName" :"Sukuna",
       "UserType" : "Villan"
    }
```

I want output like this

```
{
   "UniqeId" :1,
   "Hobbies" : "Eating",
   "UserName" :"Sukuna",
   "UserType" : "Villan"
}
```

Consider All the documents in a CollectionA will contain same fields
And you can see there is no Unique fields between the two collection, and you can see we need to apply filter in CollectionA
ie) **UniqeId=1**

I am using C#, and I can able do two DB request to get those collection details (*One req for CollectionA output and another one for CollectionB output*) and manage to combine both in API level to get the desired output, but I want to do in DB level itself,

I don't want two DB calls, that is eating the API performance, so is there anyway to achieve this in a **single DB call** or by using any **aggregate pipeline**?.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: So if you had two entries in CollectionA, then would you expect 2 results, both with Sukuna/Villain? And if you had two entires in CollectionA and CollectionB, would you expect 4 results (the combination of the first items, first and second, second and first, and then second and second from the two collection respectively)?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama , Nope, I just simply want all the fields in both of the collection in a single document, that single document will contain all the feild from both collection, Lets say CollectionA have 2 fields and CollectionB have 2 fields, The output collection will contain 4 feilds. Hope it clears and I added exact example aslo

Comment: So if you have 2 documents in each collection, you just want to merge all the fields from all documents in both collections into a single document?

Comment: Note that a collection contains documents and not all documents have to contain the same fields, even in the same collection. Also note that the results you get from a query are documents - you're not producing a new collection.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama , Yeah I changed the title from collection to document, And you are right that I need merge documents from two different collection, You can assume that all the documents in the collection will have same fields, and I will update the example for more clarity, So is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: So you would expect 3 results like [this](https://pastebin.com/fiSPaJhD)? Or at least, this is what would ultimately be produced for querying for Id = 1, then Id = 2, then Id = 3?

Comment: `[{"UniqueId":1,"Hobbies":"Eating","UserName":"Sukuna","UserType":"Villain"},{"UniqueId":2,"Hobbies":"Sleeping","UserName":"Sukuna","UserType":"Villain"},{"UniqueId":3,"Hobbies":"Walking","UserName":"Sukuna","UserType":"Villain"}]` (assuming you queried for each one and then put it in a list). Is that right?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama  In collectionA I will apply a filter to get one document, and CollectionB will have only one document, I have to merge the result of CollectionB document with the filtered CollectionA document

Comment: So that's a "yes", right? OK.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, Yes the above one also seems to fine , Atleast we will get in a single query, I will apply filter on top of that, If you know the answer please post, That helps. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time right now, but you'll probably need a [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with a pipeline to get it done.

Comment: Yeah, I already gone through it my only concern was these two collections don't have any common field, otherwise with lookup we can achieve this

Comment: On the one hand you say that you don't want two queries, but then you don't seem to want the (IMO hacky) way to achieve it without two queries.

Comment: Hi, let me clear here, I don't want two DB calls, I want the required result in a single DB call, So If there is single query for this, that is much appreciated and I believe we need a common field in two collections in order to perform lookup, Sadly in this case there is no common field

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do it with a pipeline without requiring a field to match against.

Comment: Yes, I can able to do that with the help of unionWidth and group, and YuTing posted answer with lookups, anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lookup with localField 1 and foreignField 1

```
db.a.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "b",
      localField: "1",
      foreignField: "1",
      as: "docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          { $first: "$docs" }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [ "docs", "_id" ]
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$UserName",
      doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$doc"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VLuGKYlbg85)

Comment: Thanks, I can able to do that with unionWith and group and I posted the solution here also, However I will mark this as an accepted solution, If you know any advantage of using lookup over unionWith and group(eg, In performance), Please share your thoughts. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lots of trail and error and playing with pipeline, I can able to do that in **aggregate pipeline**, and I am using **unionWith** and **group**.
Here is the C# code

```
var pipeline1= new BsonDocument("$unionWith", 
    new BsonDocument
        {
            { "coll", "CollectionB" }, 
            { "pipeline", 
    new BsonArray
            {
                new BsonDocument("$match", 
                new BsonDocument("UniqeId", 1))
            } }
        });

var pipeline2 = new BsonDocument("$group", 
    new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", 0 }, 
            { "merged", 
    new BsonDocument("$push", "$$ROOT") }
        });

var pipeline3 = new BsonDocument("$replaceRoot", 
    new BsonDocument("newRoot", 
    new BsonDocument("$mergeObjects", "$merged")));

var pipeline4 = new BsonDocument("$project", 
    new BsonDocument("_id", 0));


BsonDocument[] pipeline = new BsonDocument[] { pipeline1, pipeline2, pipeline3, pipeline4 };

var dbResponse = await collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToListAsync();
```